# jQuery Ajax GET request won't cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I am trying to take an app of mine offline. I make a few `GET` requests to load modules into the app. I have added these files to my cache manifest so the request would still work.

```
function loadReportDiv(ajaxUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        cache: true,
        url : ajaxUrl,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("REPORTS: " + ajaxUrl + "... load complete");
            $("#reports_menu_wrapper").after(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
loadReportDiv("sales_reports.html");
loadReportDiv("call_reports.html");
```

I am running the app in chrome and setting the network to "offline" in my device emulator (emulating an iPad). The files I am loading with ajax have their own javascript files which are referenced in the .html files. When I try loading `sales_reports.html` and `call_reports.html` chrome fails to load the files and spits out the url it was trying to GET, which is: `js/call_reports.js?_=1415997141636`.

The appended `?_=[timestamp]` to the filepath, is breaking my app and I can't seem to prevent it from happening. As you can see I set my cache mode for my ajax request to true in an attempt to prevent this behaviour.

### EDIT:

The version of jQuery I'm using is 1.11.1.

I have tried coding the ajax request in vanilla javascript and am having the same problem.

```
function loadReportDiv(ajaxUrl) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        console.log("REPORTS: " + ajaxUrl + "... load complete");
        $("#reports_menu_wrapper").after(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", ajaxUrl);
  xmlhttp.send();       
}
```

The error is thrown in my jQuery file at line 9631:
    // Do send the request
    // This may raise an exception which is actually
    // handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
    xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

But it is also still appending the time stamp to the request url.

Once again, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: is your code hosted on a server and that a server sets to update the timestamp?

Comment: It is on a server. I don't know what setting I'd have to change to prevent this. All I have done on the server side of things for taking this app offline was adding the MIME type for .appcache to my .htaccess.

Comment: @NabilKadimi The timestamp should only be added with `cache: false`.

Comment: Isn't it an option in your device emulator that disables caching external script?

Comment: There is an option to disable the cache while dev tools are open. I current have that setting turned off as I do want to cache this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  finally figured it out!

I have a bunch of .js libraries in my app and I guess somewhere along the way one of them is forcing ajax requests to not be cached. I have added this to my `index.html` file to counter-act that.

```
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Everything is working a-ok now!